# How can I read hdf5 files stored as 1-D array. and view them as images?

Tags: dataset, pytorch, visualization

I have a large image classification dataset stored in the format `.hdf5`. The dataset has the labels and the images stored in the `.hdf5` file. I am unable to view the images as they are store in form of an array. The dataset reading code that I have used is as follows,

```
import h5py
import numpy
f = h5py.File('data/images.hdf5', 'r')
print(list(f.keys()))
```

`['datasets']`

```
group = f['datasets']
list(group.keys())
```

`['car']`

Now when I read the group `cars` I have the following output,

```
data = group['car']
data.shape,data[0].shape,data[1].shape
```

`((51,), (383275,), (257120,)`

So it looks like there are `51` images for label `car` and images are stored as `383275` and `257120` dimensional arrays, with no information about their height and width dimensions. I want to save the images as RGB again.
Next following the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394252/convert-h5-file-to-jpg-with-python), I tried to read the images.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# hdf = h5py.File("Sample.h5",'r')
array = data[0]
img = Image.fromarray(array.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
img.save("yourimage.thumbnail", "JPEG")
img.show()
```

Unfortunately, the following error is received.

```
File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py:784, in Image.frombytes(self, data, decoder_name, *args)
    781 s = d.decode(data)
    783 if s[0] >= 0:
--> 784     raise ValueError("not enough image data")
    785 if s[1] != 0:
    786     raise ValueError("cannot decode image data")

ValueError: not enough image data
```

References I have already checked the [hdf group help library](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/how-to-store-image-in-hdf5-files-with-h5py/8892) etc.
Any help will be highly useful. Thanks.